# python email sent and received with smtplib has no content

Tags: python, smtp, raspberry-pi

I am sending email with my raspberrypi with python.
I successfully sent and received the message, but the content is missing.

Here is my code

```
import smtplib

smtpUser = 'myemail@gmail.com'
smtpPass = 'mypassword'

toAdd = 'target@gmail.com'
fromAdd = smtpUser

subject = 'Python Test'
header = 'To: ' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From: ' + fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject: ' +             subject
body = 'From within a Python script'

msg = header + '\n' + body

print header + '\n' + body

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()

s.login(smtpUser,smtpPass)
s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, msg)

s.quit()
```

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a wrapper around sending emails in python; it makes sending emails super easy: https://github.com/krystofl/krystof-utils/blob/master/python/krystof_email_wrapper.py

Use it like so:

```
emailer = Krystof_email_wrapper()

email_body = 'Hello, <br /><br />' \
             'This is the body of the email.'

emailer.create_email('sender@example.com', 'Sender Name',
                     ['recipient@example.com'],
                     email_body,
                     'Email subject!',
                     attachments = ['filename.txt'])

cred = { 'email': 'sender@example.com', 'password': 'VERYSECURE' }

emailer.send_email(login_dict = cred, force_send = True)
```

You can also look at the source code to find how it works.
The relevant bits:

```
import email
import smtplib   # sending of the emails
from email.mime.multipart   import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text        import MIMEText

self.msg = MIMEMultipart()

self.msg.preamble   = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format."

# set the sender
author = email.utils.formataddr((from_name, from_email))
self.msg['From'] = author

# set recipients (from list of email address strings)
self.msg['To' ] = ', '.join(to_emails)
self.msg['Cc' ] = ', '.join(cc_emails)
self.msg['Bcc'] = ', '.join(bcc_emails)

# set the subject
self.msg['Subject'] = subject

# set the body
msg_text = MIMEText(body.encode('utf-8'), 'html', _charset='utf-8')
self.msg.attach(msg_text)

# send the email
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.login(login_dict['email'], login_dict['password'])
session.send_message(self.msg)
session.quit()
```